# docker push image to registry get error received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net, docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, docker-registry

I hope someone can help me :))

I have a registry runing in linux/ubuntu registry:2
when I generate and push image based in docker-linux all is done.

but when I generate widows images/container like this FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8 AS build
....... build my app

but a get this error when I try to push image to registry(its running in ubuntu)

```
The push refers to repository [my registry url]
20682f4ff7bf: Layer already exists
364de9d9769f: Layer already exists
459cecac74e0: Layer already exists
d75d3f2676c0: Layer already exists
1ed8b25f5f56: Layer already exists
67814da28689: Layer already exists
a57c2fa5ac49: Layer already exists
b037a641a3b8: Layer already exists
90b1395e7b4f: Layer already exists
0a59c2d473fc: Layer already exists
1612da0ebc3b: Layer already exists
94ce506bdcf2: Skipped foreign layer
f358be10862c: Skipped foreign layer
received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

registry logs:

```
.10.16 go/go1.17.10 git-commit/f756502 os/windows arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/20.10.16 \(windows\))" vars.name="xxxxxx" vars.reference=des
time="2022-07-19T09:49:15.579829667Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" auth.user.name=admin err.code=unknown err.message="unknown error" go.version=go1.11.2 http.request.contenttype="application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" http.request.host=xxxxxx http.request.id=85ace457-2985-402e-a930-5a2e79f0b6ba http.request.method=PUT http.request.remoteaddr=xxxxx http.request.uri="xxxxxx" http.request.useragent="docker/20.10.16 go/go1.17.10 git-commit/f756502 os/windows arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/20.10.16 \(windows\))" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=4.974929ms http.response.status=500 http.response.written=523 vars.name="xxxxxx" vars.reference=des
```

thank y for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've yet to sort out the magic string that validates the URL's to Windows foreign layers (pretty sure I tried a lot of combinations). So I eventually just disabled validation completely to workaround this error:

```
docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped --name registry \
  -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY=/var/lib/registry" \
  -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_CACHE_BLOBDESCRIPTOR=inmemory" \
  -e "REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true" \
  -e "REGISTRY_VALIDATION_DISABLED=true" \
  -v "registry-data:/var/lib/registry" \
  -p "127.0.0.1:5000:5000" \
  registry:2
```

Note the `-e "REGISTRY_VALIDATION_DISABLED=true"` in the command above.

Comment: Thank you :)) @BMitch done with option -e "REGISTRY_VALIDATION_DISABLED=true"